# Some fields in PDF are showing values on windows while blank on ubuntu

Tags: pdf, itext

In PDF, values for specific elements are **showing blank on ubuntu** while for same PDF values are **showing on windows OS**. I get error when I open PDF on ubuntu as shown in attached doc.

I use java iText PDF to read values from PDF. But as values are blank on ubuntu. I get blank in processing also. PDF are confidential so I can not attach here.

[image]

Comment: Please improve your question, based on these remarks: (1.) You talk about PDF fields, but you're not telling us if you are dealing with AcroForm, XFA or hybrid forms. **I think you are talking about XFA forms.** (2.) You talk about Windows and Ubuntu, but the OS doesn't matter; it's the PDF viewer that counts. For instance: Adobe Reader supports XFA forms, but Evince does not. If you are using Adobe Reader on Ubuntu, then maybe Adobe Reader on Ubuntu lacks XFA support. (3.) if you want to share documents under NDA, [get a premium support contract](http://itextpdf.com/support).

Comment: Yes it is XFA. I also wonder why different behavior on two OS. I checked on adobe and document viewer on ubuntu. adobe supports XFA as it shows correct values for other PDF. also for other fields in same PDF.

Comment: So basically, you are saying that Adobe Reader shows the fields correctly on Windows as well as on Ubuntu, but that the standard document viewer on Ubuntu (evince?) doesn't show the fields correctly? That is very well possible, since hardly any PDF viewer other than Adobe's renders XFA correctly.

Comment: No. adobe reader on ubuntu also shoes wrong value (zero). But adobe reader on windows shows correct values.

Comment: Aha, that sounds like a bug in the Linux version of Adobe Reader. There's nothing much we at iText can do about that (unless you *flatten* the form into an ordinary PDF).

Comment: ok. I will try with updated version of adobe. But in document viewer of linux values are blank. so it is about adobe version or OS issue or some issue in file. because it works fine for other files. Also Is iText use adobe to reader to read data.

Comment: iText doesn't use Adobe software in any way to read the data from an XFA file.

Comment: ok. I convert PDF to XML using iText. But when field shows blank on linux adobe (actually have value and shows on windows OS)  I gets no value in XML. and when it shows value I get it in XML.